# How can I create my own list iterable without even using subclass?

Tags: python

I am learning Python and have developed few web applications etc. Now, I want to dig deeper and learn about the under the hood workings of Python. For that, I would like to make my own list iterable. Here is my effort so far:

```
 class CustomList:
    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.nums=args
        self.count=0
        i=0
        for arg in args:
            i+=1
        self.total=i

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.count >= self.total:
            raise StopIteration
        self.count+=1

mylist=CustomList(1,2,3,4)
for item in mylist:
    print(item)
```

Now, in my **next** function, I am unsure how to iterate through my self.nums so that my print(item) prints each item in the self.nums one by one.

I don't really want to use anything related to len(), append() etc. I want to create them on my own. So that's the future plan. For now, I can't even iterate through the user given *args.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go back another level.  args in your MyList(*args) is already an iterable.
Each list item needs to explicitly point to the next one.  So each list item needs a record of the next pointer and the data associated with it.  This could be a dict but then MyList.append would need to explicitly access the records.  For me the MyListItem class is clearer.

```
class MyListItem:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.next = None
        self.data = data

    def link_to(self, child):
        self.next = child
```

The MyList class can then use this as the nodes in it's list structure.  There may be better implementations but this is the most basic I can get to.

```
class MyList:
    def __init__(self):
        """ Create the list header record, initialised to an empty list. """
        self.top = None
        self.bottom = None
        self.curr = None    # Used to iterate through the list.

    def append(self, data):
        node = MyListItem(data) # Create the List item 
        if self.top is None:    # If the list is empty point top to node
            self.top = node
        else:
            self.bottom.link_to(node) # Otherwise point the bottom node to the new node
        self.bottom = node            # Point the bottom to the new node

    def __iter__(self): 
        self.curr = self.top      # Initialise the current pointer to top
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.curr:                   # If the curr pointer is not None
            res = self.curr.data        # Get the data
            self.curr = self.curr.next  # Set curr to next
            return res                  # Return the data
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Test it

```
test = MyList()

test.append(1)
test.append('Two')
test.append([1, 2, 3])

for node in test:
    print(node)

1
Two
[1, 2, 3]
```